How do I call a function to create a value in an sql query?
Heres a piece of my code:
def create_root_account(self):
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Accounts(AccountID, Password, StaffLevel)
         VALUES ('Admin', create_random_password(), 1)""")  # Admin password is random uuid4

        def create_random_password():
            password = uuid.uuid4().hex
            return password

This does not work, as the password is set as 'create_random_password()' and doesn't call the function to create the random password. Can someone help?

The linked duplicate shows how to pass variable values to SQL statements; you would do something like cursor.execute(sql, ('admin, create_password(), 1)).  Note that the placeholder variable (%s, ?)can be different depending on the database connector package being used.

I sincerely hope you aren't storing plain-text passwords...

in this case you want to call a Python function, so you don't want the function call in the SQL query (which is a string sent to the database server to execute) but instead you want to call the Python function in your Python code and put the result into the SQL query
